# How to control a new window using webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

So I have the driver open chrome to a webpage and then make it click a button which open a second window.

```
driver.get("https://web.com");

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('button')).click();
```

How do i switch the driver control to the new window? I wanted to try:

```
driver.switchTo().window('windowName');
```

but i can't figure out name/id of the new window in chrome. I have looked up example but they are all written for Java and other language. I am using javascript(node) webdriverjs.

Answer (score 1):

The command `driver.getAllWindowHandles()` will help you out in getting the name of the window. Check out the [API Reference Docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html) for more commands/info.